# Visual Studio 2015 - Unit testing debugging native DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-debugging

How do I step into code (unmanaged native C++ DLL) from running a Unit Test in Visual Studio 2015?
I have two projects:

```
Project1
UnitTests
```

Both are .dll libraries and the UnitTests project runs a test on a function in Project1. The project UnitTests has a reference to Project1 and links to the .lib file for Project1.

I set a breakpoint in the code in Project1, but it has no effect.
Moreover, even if I try to print to stdout from my Project1 function it can't see it anywhere, shouldn't I be able to see it in the Output window with "Show output from" = Debug?